# Best practice for error reporting with std::source_location

Tags: c++, error-handling

Among the new standard library facilities introduced in C++20, there is [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) – a class that allows us to conveniently capture and handle information that was previously only accessible through implementation defined macros like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__`. My understanding is that its intended usage is in logging and error reporting functions. E.g., a function declared as

```
void log(const char* message, std::source_location src_loc = std::source_location::current())
```

can log a message including source file name and line from its call location. However, having experimented a little, I am tempted to use `source_location` more broadly and I'm wondering if it would be good practice.

For the sake of an example, let's assume that I am developing an application that might encounter a particular error that it has no reasonable way of recovering from. The only thing to do is shutdown, but I would like to make sure to log some useful information about the circumstances that led to the error. I will present some very simplified snippets of code, in this question I want to focus only on reporting the location of the error, so I will skip the details on logging other information or shutting down the program.

Let's say that the error always occurs in the function `foo`. A simple way of reporting it would be:

```
int foo(double x)
{
  // ...
  if (error_occurred)
  {
    log(error_message);
    // shutdown
  }
  // ...
}
```

However, this will report the error from the call site of `log` which is always the exact same line from the implementation of `foo`. This is not very useful, especially if `foo` is a low level function that is called multiple times from various places in the code. It would be more helpful to report the location of the call to `foo` that resulted in the error. I would like to compare two ways of approaching that problem.

#### 1. Throw an exception

Let's say that we have functions like `fun_1`, `fun_2`,... that call `foo`. We could modify `foo` to

```
int foo(double x)
{
  // ...
  if (error_occurred)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error{error_message};
  }
  // ...
}
```

and then inside `fun_1`:

```
try
{
  n = foo(x);
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& error)
{
  log(error.what());
  // shutdown
}
```

This way `log` will report the location of the catch block associated with the call to `foo`.

#### 2. Propagate `source_location`

Alternatively, we could modify the signature and body of `foo`:

```
int foo(double x, std::source_location src_loc = std::source_location::current())
{
  // ...
  if (error_occurred)
  {
    log(error_message, src_loc);
    // shutdown
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then, without doing anything other than `n = foo(x);` inside `fun_1` we get the same report as in approach 1. (Even slightly better since it points directly at the call of `foo` rather than the `catch` block.)

Neither of these approaches is fully satisfactory since they both add some noise to the code, but I suppose this is unavoidable with error handling, the question is how to minimize it. I see the following problems.

1. Throwing an exception

- The call sites of `foo` are heavily polluted. If there are many functions like `fun_1` and `fun_2` perhaps each calling `foo` multiple times and we want to report precisely which of the calls caused the error, then each has to be decorated by `try`/`catch` blocks.

2. Propagating `source_location`

- The signature of `foo` is polluted.
- If there is a longer stack of calls between `foo` and `fun_1` then we will have to pollute signatures and call sites of all intermediate functions.

I believe that approach 1 is fairly standard practice in C++, but I couldn't find any information about using `source_location` the way I propose. Would it be a good idea? Is it reasonable to use `source_location` as a parameter in functions belonging to "production code" as opposed to just dedicated error handling functions? Could this lead to any problems that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Consider option 3

```
int foo(double x)
{
  // ...
  if (error1_occurred)
  {
    log(error_message, std::source_location::current());
    // shutdown
  } else if (error2_occured) {
    log(error_message, std::source_location::current());
  }
  // ...
}
```

When there are multiple errors you want to know wehre it came from. You want to know the source_location of where the error occured, not somewhere up the call stack. This isnt noise, but it is adding valuable information to your log output.

On the other hand, if you do want to collect information somewhere up, consider option 4:

```
int foo(double x)
{
  // ...
  if (error_occurred)
  {
    throw my_error{error_message,std::source_location::current()};
  }
  // ...
}
```

> This is not very useful, especially if foo is a low level function that is called multiple times from various places in the code

That is no different from the old `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros. They show the file/line of where they are replaced by the preprocessor. `std::source_location` works similar.

All that being said, it is up to you to decide which information you want to include in a log. There is no one-fits-all solution.

Comment: You don't address my questions at all. Your option 3 is my "option 0". The entire premise of the question is that this might be insufficient since `foo` may not have enough information to tell why the error occurred. As far as it is concerned, there is no `error1_occurred` or `error2_occurred`, only `error_occurred`. Your option 4 doesn't accomplish anything beyond what option 1 does. It doesn't matter which type of exception it throws since it has no information that could be conveyed by the exception type.